# How can one have two test suites related to different applications in the same plugin?

Tags: plugins, symfony1, phpunit

I am currently working with sfPhpUnitPlugin on a sf 1.4 project, and I am facing a problem with plugin testing.

I have a plugin that can be used on several applications, and I would like to have a test suite per application. How can I organize my tests so that I can easily match fixtures and tests with a specific application?

My suites are copies of this template, which is delivered with the sfPhpunitPlugin:

```
<?php

class {className} extends sfBasePhpunitTestSuite
  implements sfPhpunitContextInitilizerInterface
{
    /**
     * Dev hook for custom "setUp" stuff
     */
    protected function _start()
    {
      $this->_initFilters();
    }

    /**
     * Dev hook for custom "tearDown" stuff
     */
    protected function _end()
    {
    }

    protected function _initFilters()
    {
      $filters = sfConfig::get('app_sfPhpunitPlugin_filter', array());
      foreach ($filters as $filter) {
        PHPUnit_Util_Filter::addDirectoryToFilter($filter['path'], $filter['ext']);
      }
    }

    public function getApplication()
    {
      return '{application}';
    }
}
```

I suppose I have to add something like this in the app.yml of each application:

```
testunit:
  sfPhpunitPlugin:
    filter:
      - {path: 'backend', ext: '.php'}
```

but I have difficulty determining what the path key is going to look like, I'm under the impression it should be a full path, because the include_path does not contain the path of the plugin I'm testing when `addDirectoryToFilter()` is called.
Any tips?
Has anyone done this yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually You have to create two suite classes which implemented *sfPhpunitContextInitilizerInterface* interface and implement all required methods.

Then put those two suites in two different folders, for example:

SF_PLUGIN_DIR/YOUR_PLUGIN/test/phpunit/unit/app1/App1TestSuite.php
SF_PLUGIN_DIR/YOUR_PLUGIN/test/phpunit/unit/app2/App2TestSuite.php

All tests in directory app1 or subdirectories will be run in symfony app defined in App1TestSuite.php and the same rules for app2 directory.

If you want to run tests dynamically in different applications you can define this logic in methods required by interface (getEnviroment and getApplication).

Feel free to ask me if you still have any questions.

Comment: Is the app defined by the `getApplication()` method? With your method, is the config I added in my app (see question) still needed or not?

Comment: The filters functionality is not related with setting application context. In next the plugin release I will remove it is because the filter behavior was changed in phpunit 3.5 version.

Comment: The app.yml is not used any more for the plugin configuration instead the plugin has it is own called phpunit.yml

Comment: sfPhpunitContextInitilizerInterface defines two methods getApplication and getEnvironment. Both these methods should return string represented application and environment. All other work to setup configuration and init context will do the plugin internally. If you want to look in detail look at sfBasePhpunitTestSuite::setupContext method.

Comment: thank you for this explanation, I just had a look at this method, it is much more clearer!